# How to set a static minimum value for axes in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have time-based data that ranges from 1 to 500. Time is plotted on the x axis and the values are on the y axis.

When the range between the minimum and maximum data-points is great the y-axis' start label is 0. I can tell Highcharts not to display the label by setting `yAxis.startOnTick = false;` but that's is not really what I'm after.

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nQkWG/560/) of the problem where you cannot tell if the first point is 0 or some other value. Having 0 here also looks like the min range for y is 
 0, not 1.

Can Highcharts display the first label and the first label should always be set to the minimum value in the dataset (relative to its axis).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am amazed how difficult this is.  Not an optimal solution, but the best [I can dream up](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/KS99A/2/) with HighChart's api:

```
var someData = [1,5,82,9,300,5,42,199,5,6,99,1,56,52,250,64];

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    yAxis:{
        min: -10,
        tickInterval: 1,
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                if (this.value < someData[0])
                    return null;
                else if (this.value == someData[0])
                    return this.value;
                else if (this.value % 50 == 0)
                    return this.value;
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: someData
    }]

});
```

[image]

Comment: +1. This is much better than what I came up with - I was just telling Highcharts that when the label is "0", display "1" instead. I'll need to do some additional pre-processing of the data to get your solution to work 100% withmy datasets, i.e., setting the appropriate tick interval and determining the lowest value in the dataset. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I'll also probably do some additional processing for only setting the tickInterval to 1 when Highcharts is going to want to set the first label to "0", unless there really isn't that much overhead involved when calling `labels.formatter` up to 500 times.

Comment: This not works anymore, with version 4. I'm still searching a solution.

Comment: @sylouuu, seems to still work with v4: http://jsfiddle.net/KS99A/32/, just had to update the js include.

Answer (score 3):

A solution (that optimizes [Marks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8196108/2732991)) is to use `yAxis.labels.formatter` with `this.isFirst` and `this.axis.dataMin`, like this:

```
yAxis:{
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            if(this.isFirst)
                return this.axis.dataMin;
            return this.value;
        }
    }
}
```

See [this JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nQkWG/703/) for an example.

The advantage of this is that you do not have to manually set `tickInterval`, which saves a lot of calls to `formatter` and lets Highcharts figure out the label intervals itself. Also, it uses the axis knowledge of the minimum data value, instead of having to check against an array (which you may have to iterate over to find the minimum).

Beware that the `yAxis.min` must be set to something sensible here (works best with `0`, and positive data). If the y-axis goes far below the minimum datapoint the first label will not be the one at 0.

The `this.axis` value was not available when this question was asked.