# Change first tick label on yAxis

Tags: highcharts

I need change first tick label on yAxis. I changed the minimum value on the yAxis:

```
yAxis: [{
    title : {
        text : 'Position'
    },
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    startOnTick: false, 
    min: 1, //changed min value
    reversed: true,
}]
```

but the value is not shown in front yAxis. How to sign the first value in the yAxis?

Here's my [chart](http://test.shtalber.ru/charts/chart2.php).

if I write:

```
yAxis: [{
    title : {
    text : 'Позиция'
    },
    startOnTick: false, 
    showFirstLabel: true,
    min: 1,
    reversed: true, 
    tickInterval: 1,
    labels: {
          formatter: function() {
            if (this.value < 1)
                return null;
            else if (this.value == 1)
                return this.value;
            else if (this.value % 2 == 0)
                    return this.value;
        }
    }
```

}]
then scaling yAxis turns bad for my data :( [chart](http://test.shtalber.ru/charts/chart.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own [yAxis.tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.tickPositioner) to define all positions where you wish a tick should be placed.

Since in your case you don't want to override the entire behavior, but just place a tick at the min position, you can leverage the `axis.getLinearTickPositions(interval, min, max)` method to get the array of default positions that would be otherwise generate, and then append your additional ticks to this array.

The code below has ticks added on both the min and max of the y-axis

```
yAxis: {
    showFirstLabel: true,
    showLastLabel: true,
    tickPositioner: function(min, max) {
        // specify an interval for ticks or use max and min to get the interval
        var interval = Math.round((max - min) / 5);
        var dataMin = this.dataMin;
        var dataMax = this.dataMax;
        // push the min value at beginning of array
        var positions = [dataMin];
        var defaultPositions = this.getLinearTickPositions(interval, dataMin, max);
        //push all other values that fall between min and max
        for (var i = 0; i < defaultPositions.length; i++) {
            if (defaultPositions[i] > dataMin && defaultPositions[i] < dataMax) {
                positions.push(defaultPositions[i]);
            }
        }
        // push the max value at the end of the array
        positions.push(dataMax);
        return positions;
    }
}
```

[Show tick on min and max of y axis | Highchart & Highstock @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/cNgrJ/)
[Demo of your chart @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/cNgrJ/11/)

Comment: thanx! but if you look at my example http://regexinfo.ru/charts/chart_good_scale.php, where there is no sign to the value of 1, and look at your examplehttp://regexinfo.ru/charts/chart_good_scale1.php On my example Automatic scaling and better. I need only to sign a value of 1 if it appears when scrolling.

Comment: Sorry, may be you can rephrase the question for me to understand exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I need scale(my chart): http://regexinfo.ru/charts/my_chart.JPG your chart: http://regexinfo.ru/charts/your_chart.JPG and If I'm to the left Stsrollbar there should appear a value of 1: http://regexinfo.ru/charts/i_need.JPG

Comment: If i get what you are saying, can you try removing the `if` inside the for and then try? Sorry I gtg for now, will try to mashup something once I am back

Comment: Ok by looking at the screenshots I think I get what you want, will get back after a few hours

Comment: can you check http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/cNgrJ/11/ @I.Zaytsev I think with the custom tickPositioner approach, you can achieve what you are looking for, what I have posted may not exactly meet the need but should hopefully lead you in the right direction

Comment: I have another question. I added a data type flag. I want to hide "Series 2" ScreenShot: http://regexinfo.ru/charts/hide_series.JPG

Comment: @I.Zaytsev Let's not overload a single question with multiple problems, it becomes difficult for other users with similar users to search questions inside comments. Please consider posting different questions

Comment: @I.Zaytsev check http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.flags.showInLegend

Answer (score 0):

For me it seems everything is working fine. The minimum value of your reversed chart is 1, which is right on top of the y-Axis. However if you want to show this value on the axis, have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189921/how-to-set-a-static-minimum-value-for-axes-in-highcharts) for a description.

Comment: on your link did not work to fix the problem. edited the question again

Comment: Of course you have to adjust the y-axis step to your needs. Change the last line of the else-if condition to `(this.value % 20 == 0)` - thats what I remember from the scaling in your first example.

Comment: then it turns scaling fixed but I don't like this... please look this example: [link](regexinfo.ru/charts/chart_good_scale.php) I have good scale but the value 1 is not signed by one yAxis if I move to the left until the end of ScrollBar(opposite the yAxis is sign "first value: 0")