# highcharts yaxis start on 1 min:1 not working

Tags: highcharts

I need my yaxis in highcharts to always start on 1, not 0.  My data sets are whole numbers with 1 being the lowest, i've tried everything combination on min, minrange startontick, that I could think of. The only way I was able to get the yaxis to show 1 instead of zero is with the snippet below. I basically hid the 0, then set a custom label for that plot band giving it a label of `1`. Is this the only way?

```
yAxis: {
            min:1,
            showFirstLabel: false,
            allowDecimals : false,
            reversed: true,
            plotBands: [{
                color: '#EBFAEB',
                from: 0,
                to: 10,
                label: {
                    text: '1',
                    style: {
                    color: '#000000',
                    },
                    align: 'left',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    y: 0,
                    x: -15
                }
            }],
```

Sample data i'm using

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [7, 6, 9, 14, 18, 21, 25, 26, 23, 18, 13, 9]
    }, {
        name: 'New York',
        data: [13, 2, 1, 11, 17, 22, 24, 24, 20, 14, 8, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Berlin',
        data: [1, 3, 3, 8, 13, 17, 18, 17, 14, 9, 3, 1]
    }, {
        name: 'London',
        data: [3, 4, 5, 8, 11, 15, 17, 16, 14, 10, 6, 4]
    }]
```

Answer (score 6):

It's probably because your tickInterval scales to something such that it wont' start at 0.  min:1 should work if you give it an appropriate tickInterval.

Alternatively min:1 combined with startOnTick: false should also work.

EDIT:

I just tried the following combination myself and it works for me.  If you tried this before and it didn't work for you then the issue is probably that you the proper case for the different options:

```
min: 1,
startOnTick: false,
tickInterval: 10
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/Reality_Extractor/kTmqg/

Comment: Hi with `min:1` and `tickinterval:1` it works but way too many plotbands, can I some how have it display a band one every 10 tick positions? so it'd be 1 10 20 30 etc?

Comment: I've edited my question to show the sample data series i'm using

Comment: @Anagio I edited my answer, I just tried it with those options and it worked, be sure that you use the capital O and T in startOnTick.

Comment: That works yes but it's not displaying the number 1 where 0 was in the bottom left corner. It's just hiding the first tick. I'm thinking i'll have to create multiple custom plotband labels to get it to work the way I need.

Comment: @Anagio in that case this is probably a solution that will work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189921/how-to-set-a-static-minimum-value-for-axes-in-highcharts

Comment: Thanks, it's not an optimal solution but works just as well as setting all the plotband labels

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use tickPositioner?

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.tickPositioner

Comment: This is the correct answer - with tickPositioner I was able to replace the 0 tick with 1 and now it displays 1 10 20 30 etc...